Smallest eigenvalue of matrix with random elements (non-central Wishart)
Suppose that $X \in \mathbb R^{d \times n}$ is a random matrix with independent entries, each of which follows the standard normal law $\mathcal N(0, 1)$, and that $M \in \mathbb R^{d \times n}$ is a given non-random matrix. Consider the random matrices
$$
A = XX^\top \in \mathbb R^{d\times d}, \qquad B = (X + M)(X + M)^\top \in \mathbb R^{d \times d}.
$$
Intuitively, it seems to me that the following statement should hold true irrespectively of $d$, $n$ and $M$:
$$
\tag{1}
\forall r \geq 0, \qquad
\mathbb P\Big[\lambda_{\min}(A) \geq r \Bigl] ≤ \mathbb P\Big[\lambda_{\min}(B) \geq r \Bigl].
$$
This appears to be a simple statement, but I have not found it in the literature on non-central Wishart distributions. Does (1) follow from known results, or is there a simple approach to prove or disprove it?
Case $d = 1$. The statement is true in this case. Indeed, for each $i \in \{1, \dotsc, n\}$ let $(X_i, Y_i)$ denote a coupling  (with couplings for different values of $i$ independent of each other) such that
$$
X_i \sim \mathcal N(0, 1), \qquad 
Y_i \sim \mathcal N(m_i, 1), \qquad
$$
and additionally
$$
|X_i| \leq |Y_i| \qquad \text{almost surely}.
$$
Showing that such a coupling exists is not difficult.
Then $Y$ is equal in law to $X + M$ and
$$
XX^\top = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i^2 = YY^\top \qquad \text{almost surely.}
$$
The conclusion then follows easily.

Did you prove it for $d=n=1?$

Hi Prof Letac. I am so happy that you are commenting here, thank you! Your "tutorial on non central Wishart distributions" is one of the first places I looked to answer my qusetion. Yes, the case $d = n = 1$ is simple. I am at a workshop today and tomorrow, but will try to write it out in full tomorrow evening.

The paper that you mention contains a subtle mistake pointed out by E. Mayerhofer. We corrected it in 2018 Journal of Multivariate Analysis, volume 163 pages 96-110. E. Mayerhofer published another solution in the general frame of Euclidean Jordan Algebras in the Transactions of the American Math. Soc, arXiv 1104.0784v. Your solution for $d=1$ is simple and elegant.

Thank you very much for the reference, I'll have a look at it!
